# Can't load image into pygame

Tags: python, pygame

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uy8DN.png)I am learning python from a book called "Computer Coding Python Games For Kids"
Here's the book[https://www.amazon.com/Computer-Coding-Python-Games-Kids/dp/0241317797](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0241317797)
The game is basically where you try to click on the red snowflake before it gets to the bottom
My problem is that even if I store the image with the code in the same file it can't seem to find the image.
If I try to write (C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\python-games\find the red snowflake\image\red-snow)I get a Unicode error.
here is my code

```
import pgzrun
import random

FONT_COLOUR = (255,255,255)
WIDTH = 1920
HEIGHT = 1080
CENTER_X = WIDTH/2
CENTER_Y = HEIGHT/2
CENTER = (CENTER_X,CENTER_Y)
FINAL_LEVEL = 15
START_SPEED = 10
COLOURS = ["green","blue"]

game_over = False
game_complete = False
current_level = 1
snows =[]
animations =[]

def draw():
    global snows,current_level,game_over,game_complete
    screen.clear()
    screen.blit("moutain",(0,0))
    if game_over:
        display_message("GAME OVER!","Try again.")
    elif game_complete:
        display_message("YOU WON!","Well done.")
    else:
        for snow in snows:
            snow.draw()


def update():
    global snows
    if len(snows) == 0:
        snows = make_snows(current_level)

def make_snows(number_of_extra_snows):
    colours_to_create=get_colours_to_create(number_of_extra_snows)
    new_snows = create_snows(colours_to_create)
    layout_snows(new_snows)
    animate_snows(new_snows)
    return new_snows

def get_colours_to_create(number_of_extra_snows):
    colours_to_create = ["red"]
    for i in range(0,number_of_extra_snows):
        random_colour = random.choice(COLOURS)
        colours_to_create.append(random_colour)
    return colours_to_create

def create_snows(colours_to_create):
    new_snows=[]
    for colour in colours_to_create:
        snow = Actor(r"C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\python-games\find the red snowflake\image\red-snow") 
        new_snows.append(snow)
    return new_snows

def layout_snows(snows_to_layout):
    number_of_gaps = len(snows_to_layout) + 1
    gap_size = WIDTH/number_of_gaps
    random.shuffle(snoews_to_layout)
    for index,snow in enumerate(snows_to_layout):
        new_x_pos = (index + 1) * gap_size
        snow.x = new_x_pos

def animate_snows(snows_to_animate):
    for snow in snows_to_animate:
        duration = START_SPEED - current_level
        snow.anchor = ("center","bottom")
        animation = animate(snow,duration=duration, on_finished=handle_game_over,y=HEIGHT)
        animations.append(animation)

def handle_game_over():
    global game_over
    game_over = True

def on_mouse_down(pos):
    global snows,current_level
    for snow in snows:
        if snow.collidepoint(pos):
            if "red" in snow.image:
                red_snow_click()
            else:
                handle_game_over()

def red_snow_click():
    global current_level,snows, animations,game_complete
    stop_animations(animations)
    if currents_level == FINAL_LEVEL:
        game_complete = True
    else:
        current_level = current_level + 1
        snows = []
        animations =[]

def stop_animations(animations_to_stop):
    for animation in animations_to_stop:
        if animation.running:
            animation.stop()

def display_message(heading_text,sub_heading_text):
    screen.draw.text(heading_text, fontsize = 60, center=CENTRE,COLOR=FONT_COLOUR)
    screen.draw.text(sub_heading_text,
                     fontsize=30,
                     center=(CENTRE_X,CENTER_Y +30),
                     color=FONT_COLOUR)
pgzrun.go()
```

and this is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\python-games\find the red snowflake\image\find the red snowflake.py", line 108, in <module>
    pgzrun.go()
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pgzrun.py", line 31, in go
    run_mod(mod)
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pgzero\runner.py", line 113, in run_mod
    PGZeroGame(mod).run()
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pgzero\game.py", line 217, in run
    self.mainloop()
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pgzero\game.py", line 252, in mainloop
    update(dt)
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pgzero\game.py", line 194, in <lambda>
    return lambda dt: update()
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\python-games\find the red snowflake\image\find the red snowflake.py", line 36, in update
    snows = make_snows(current_level)
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\python-games\find the red snowflake\image\find the red snowflake.py", line 40, in make_snows
    new_snows = create_snows(colours_to_create)
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\python-games\find the red snowflake\image\find the red snowflake.py", line 55, in create_snows
    snow = Actor(r"C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\python-games\find the red snowflake\image\red-snow")
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pgzero\actor.py", line 88, in __init__
    self.image = image
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pgzero\actor.py", line 103, in __setattr__
    return object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pgzero\actor.py", line 218, in image
    self._orig_surf = self._surf = loaders.images.load(image)
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pgzero\loaders.py", line 120, in load
    self.validate_root(name)
  File "C:\Users\Nigel\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pgzero\loaders.py", line 99, in validate_root
    raise KeyError(
KeyError: "No 'images' directory found to load image 'C:\\Users\\Nigel\\Desktop\\python-games\\find the red snowflake\\image\\red-snow'."
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're getting a unicode error for that path, that means you're probably not typing it right -- those backwards slashes you see in paths are normally used for "escape characters", and they can interfere when you're just trying to type the path to a file. Try one of these solutions, if you haven't already typed your path like this:

```
r"C:\Users\Nigel\Desktop\python-games\find the red snowflake\image\red-snow"         # type r before the opening quote to make it a raw-string, which ignores escape characters
"C:\\Users\\Nigel\\Desktop\\python-games\\find the red snowflake\\image\\red-snow"   # use double-slashes to escape being an escape character
```

Also, make sure you add the file extension for your image in the path.

Comment: if I do that then it says there is no directory found even if they are in they same file. thanks though

Comment: @pythonnoob What's the exact error you get, and what's the exact code you wrote for the path that caused it?

Comment: @thisismy-stackoverflowTraceback (most recent call last):
 KeyError: "No 'images' directory found to load image 'red-snow'."

Comment: @pythonnoob Can you edit your original question to add the exact code you're using where this happens? Just so I can get a better visualization of what's going on

Comment: It is at def create_snow

Comment: @pythonnoob What's the file extension for the "red-snow" image?

Comment: the extension is png

Comment: @pythonnoob Wait, when it says "images" directory, were you supposed to create a folder called "images" and put the image in there? Try doing that, and loading just "red-snow" again without the full path.

Comment: that was what I had orrignally  nut it gave the smae error

Comment: @pythonnoob Are you sure? Because in all your code examples, your folder is called "image" without the 's'